# iOS7.1 - can't change center of view using UIPanGestureRecognizer and AutoLayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, autolayout, uipangesturerecognizer

I have I view that I want to move around using `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. This view is placed inside a `UICollectionViewCell` subclass. I'm using `AutoLayout` to layout the view. The constraints looks like this:

```
[self.contentView addSubview:self.containerView];
    [self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[_containerView(==290)]" options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_containerView)]];

[self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(15)-[_containerView]" options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_containerView)]];

self.containerViewHeightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.containerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1 constant:350];

self.containerViewRightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.containerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1 constant:15];

[self.contentView addConstraints:@[self.containerViewHeightConstraint, self.containerViewRightConstraint]];
```

It is this `containerView` that I want to move around using the `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. In `cellForItemAtIndexPath` I add my recogniser to this view: `[cell.containerView addGestureRecognizer:self.resultPanRecognizer];`.

The relevant part of my selector for my resultPanRecognizer (`UIPanGestureRecognizer`) looks like this:

```
// Should reposition the view, works in iOS8.1, but not iOS7. 
CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.collectionView];
recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x,
                                     recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);
[recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.collectionView];
```

So, my code works perfectly in iOS 8, but in iOS7.1 the view resets it's position to it's original position as soon as the user starts panning.

My theories have been, inconsistent behaviour of UICollectionViews (specifically their content views) between iOS7 and 8, or that my AutoLayout `constraints` is causing the view to get reset on iOS7.

But I haven't found any workaround that worked.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm surprised that this worked in iOS 8. When you use constraints, you shouldn't be setting any frames, you should be adjusting the constraints. The auto layout system should reset the frame to that defined by your constraints, so the iOS 7 behavior is what I would expect to see given your code.

Comment: Is the collection view pan gesture conflicting with the draggable view? Did you set delegate to accept simultaneous recognizers?

Comment: @HenryTKirk Hi, I don't allow scrolling in the tableView, so there shouldn't be any conflicts.